# Random number generation from a given distribution

Tags: random

Is there any way to obtain random numbers from a user defined continuous distribution in Mathematica?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [RandomVariate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomVariate.html)?

Comment: Go to Scope -> Derived distributions, and there are examples of how to use `RandomVariate`.